# Macros or Scala Reflect - extract all parameter names as a list of string routes

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Given I have a case class with a lot of different parameter types, I want to collect all parameter names in a dot notation.
Example:

```
case class Language(name: String, locale: String)
case class Author(name: String)
case class ContentType(name: String)
case class Content(text: String, contentType: ContentType, created: DateTime)
case class Page(language: Language, author: Author, content: Content, description: Option[String])
```

This would return:

```
Seq(
  "language.name",
  "language.locale"
  "author.name",
  "content.text",
  "content.contentType.name",
  "content.created",
  "description",
  "description.value"
)
```

The main issue here is that the macros expansion I'm using is very very expensive, so I feel the macro solution is no the best route to solve this problem or the implementation is very poor.
Is there a better way for 2.11.8+?, 2.11.6works fine

Comment: Macros are usually cheaper than e.g. shapeless but more error-prone and harder in maintenance. If you feel that currently it it slow, changing the implementation to something shapeless-like would surely not make it optimal. My guess is that there is some expensive calculation in your macros that you could skip, e.g. you might recalculate the data for a class that is used in several places. Maybe a type class with semiauto? Something that would let you cache the computations for reuse?

Comment: Just to clarify: shapeless might be faster than your macro if you really messed up and made it reaally ineffective, so you might give it a shot, though if you already went with macros, you might as well try to optimize them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a use case for [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/)

```
import scala.meta._
import scala.meta.dialects.Scala212

println(
  """
    |case class Language(name: String, locale: String)
    |case class Author(name: String)
    |case class ContentType(name: String)
    |case class Content(text: String, contentType: ContentType, created: DateTime)
    |case class Page(language: Language, author: Author, content: Content, description: Option[String])
  """.stripMargin.parse[Source].get.collect {
    case q"..$_ class $tname[..$_] ..$_ (...$paramss) extends $_" =>
      paramss.flatten.map { case param"..$_ $pname: $_ = $_" =>
        s"$tname.$pname"
      }
  }.flatten
)
//List(Language.name, Language.locale, Author.name, ContentType.name, Content.text, Content.contentType, Content.created, Page.language, Page.author, Page.content, Page.description)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this project is in 2.11.x series, I think scalameta  only works for 2.12

Comment: @raul782 No. It works with 2.11. Write in `build.sbt`: `scalaVersion := "2.11.11"`
`libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "3.7.4"` and change import to `import scala.meta.dialects.Scala211`.